# Spring Security with Roles

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I know, this question are posted multiple times but all the answers dont help me, also i will post here my case.

My configuration of SpringBoot-Project looks like:

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/secure/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .hasRole(ERole.USER.name);

        http.formLogin().loginPage("/auth").permitAll();
    }
}
```

**Enum with Roles**

```
public enum ERole implements GrantedAuthority {
    USER("USER");

    public final String name;

    ERole(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

**Custom Authentication**

```
public class UserAuth implements Authentication {
    // Implements all the methods ...
    // getAuthorities() return the list of ERole
}
```

**Auth REST Controller**

```
@RestController
public class AuthRestCtrl {
    public static final String PERMIT_URL = AuthCtrl.INDEX_URL + "/rest/permit";

    private ShaPasswordEncoder shaPasswordEncoder = new ShaPasswordEncoder();

    /**
     * Führt die Authentifizierung des Nutzers durch
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/auth/rest/permit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public boolean permitUser(@RequestBody AuthData authData) {
        Account account = new Account();
        account.setLogin("test");
        account.setSalt("");
        account.setPassword(this.shaPasswordEncoder.encodePassword("123456", account.getSalt()));
        account.addRole(ERole.USER);

        User user = new User();
        user.setName("...");
        user.setSurname("...");
        user.setAccount(account);

        if (!authData.getUsername().equals(account.getLogin())) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!this.shaPasswordEncoder.isPasswordValid(account.getPassword(), authData.getPassword(), account.getSalt())) {
            return false;
        }

        UserAuth userAuth = new UserAuth(user);
        userAuth.setAuthenticated(true);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(userAuth);

        ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        attr.getRequest().getSession(true).setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
        return true;
    }
```

Now if i redirect (via javascript after my restclient returns true) to any secure page "/secure/home" i get status 403. I read that status 403 means the user have wrong role, but dont know what i did wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: You are using Spring Security completely wrong. Spring Security supplies filters (as in `javax.servlet.Filter`) to handle authentication. Do not create a controller for that. If you need custom authentication, create your own filter or a `UserDetailsService`. In any case, please read the documentation again carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, i find it out. In SecurityConfig on ".hasRole(ERole.USER.name);" spring will attach *ROLE_* prefix automatically. But the user have role *USER* and not *ROLE_USER*. I solved this problem in *getAuthority()*-method:

```
@Override
public String getAuthority() {
    return "ROLE_" + this.name;
}
```

I know i use the SpringSecurity eventuelly not correct way, but this actuelly works for me (in my SpringBoot test project)